# SDL - not loading an image

Tags: c++, sdl

This is the first time I'm trying out separating my files into 4 folders: images, source, sounds, headers. My problem is: I'm trying to load a trivial BMP from the images folder that has been called on by a file in the source folder. Here is my code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    hello = SDL_LoadBMP("../images/hello.bmp");

    SDL_BlitSurface(hello, NULL, screen, NULL);

    SDL_Flip(screen);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    SDL_FreeSurface(hello);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;   

}
```

Apparently, the call "../images/hello.bmp" isn't working.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are running your program from the source directory as well? Remember that the path relativity will be from wherever you're *running* the program from, not necessarily where you *compiled* it from.

Comment: Oh, no. I was running the program from the main folder. That is my problem! Thank you for clarifying that for me! :D

Comment: You should probably have a bin folder, where your final distribution is laid out.  You should set that as the directory for your binary output file. Your images and sounds folder should be in there too, but not your source and headers, since, presumably, they would not be part of the distribution.

Answer (score 6):

I think you forgot to call `SDL_Init()`.